# How to link the questions with each other (also, if they are not marked as duplicate)?

Tags: discussion, support

I have tried to find an answer to the question: How do I link the questions with each other?

And have not found any. I know, that if questions are marked as duplicate, then there is a link section on the right side with linked duplicate questions.

Who can link the questions and how?

Comment: example for answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow

Comment: *Linked* - is a collection of all SO links leading **from** current page (question, answer and comments) and **into** current from other SO questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a "link" to a question by simply commenting on the question with a link the the question you want to link to.  After you do that you will see in the linked section in the right hand side bar the question you linked to.

You can see this here.  I linked to a FAQ main page in [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348665/how-to-link-the-questions-with-each-otheralso-if-they-are-not-marked-as-dupli#comment470179_348665) and now it shows up as linked.