# Is it bad form to use someone else's code from a different question

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I came across a question the other day (how to put two divs side by side in css?) so I googled "two divs side by side" and picked the top link (How to align two divs side by side using the float, clear, and overflow elements with a fixed position div/) and copy/pasted the code from the answer there. Later I thought perhaps I shouldn't have done that as someone else wrote it. Is that right?

**Edit**

The answer isn't exactly the same, but the code is.

Comment: Why are the questions not duplicates if the same answer can answer both of them?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea; There appear to be a lot of side by side div positioning questions

Comment: Seems dangerous to post an answer if you don't understand the questions.

Comment: I do understand the questions, I just don't understand why they are different

Comment: If you don't think they are different flag one as a duplicate of the other. That's far better than posting duplicate answers.

Comment: I guess because the latter question wants to use specific css to go about it...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will do that. That doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: _"so I googled "two divs side by side" and picked the top link"_ - and that's why JavaScript, CSS and PHP tags are the lauging stock for the rest of the site. The amount of reputation you can earn by that process to answer questions of people who don't know how to Google is astonishing.  But no, you definitely shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Did you attribute the code that you copy and pasted?  If not you should know that all content you copy from somewhere into your answer needs to be attributed otherwise that is called plagiarism.

Comment: I did add a comment on my answer saying "I got the code from here"

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, I won't do that in the future then.

Comment: More on attribution - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302295/should-i-fix-plagiarism-that-is-caused-by-missing-attribution and even more https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+answer+attribution

Comment: For what it's worth, you shouldn't do this with your own answers either.

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question has an **answer** in another question (even if the question is different), that's generally a duplicate. If you click the flag button under the question, you can request it be closed as a duplicate and people will review it in the queue.

If, however, you're merely **referencing** it to **make a new answer specific to the question** then that's fine. Be sure to link to the original source and specify what you did to change it for that question.

Comment: Ok, I will do that next time.

Comment: I have not known how to link the questions, now I know it ;) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348665/7713750